# Compute convex hull of points in a feature collection

Tags: geometry, features, google-earth-engine, convex-hull, multipoint

I uploaded an asset (which was originally a shapefile of points) and imported it into my script as a feature collection, with each point being an independent isolated feature.

I would like to compute the convex hull of all the points, i.e. to calculate a polygon that includes all points, all features, of this feature collection.

However, it seems this function is only available for geometry objects. Using this function in each feature would not achieve our goal, since it would apply a convex hull to each point in isolation.

I have been trying several methods to convert the feature collection to multi-point geometry, but nothing seems to be the correct incantation. How would one convert a feature collection to multi-point geometry (or am I missing the mark in how I'm approaching this)?

I'm open to any GEE solution that accomplishes the main goal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do exactly, as that is missing. But I guess the problem is you want use convexHull(maxError, proj), which is available on ee.Feature and ee.Geometry.
You say you actually have a ee.FeatureCollection, therefore you will need to map every feature of the feature collection to use the convexHull. This would look something like this.

```js
var newFeatures = uploadedAsset.map(function(x){
  return ee.Feature(x.convexHull());
  });
print(newFeatures)
```